# How to add the first part of an url in a object value before sending it to json encode

Tags: arrays, object, eloquent, slim

I query the db for a list of images:

```
$rows = $db->table('images')->where('attivo', 1)->get();
```

I get the following object:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#107 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#96 (12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["img"]=>
      string(11) "example.jpg"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2018-07-26 20:33:59"
      ["attivo"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#88 (12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(4)
      ["img"]=>
      string(12) "img.png"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2018-07-26 20:33:59"
      ["attivo"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#103 (12) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(5)
      ["img"]=>
      string(9) "test2.jpg"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(19) "2018-07-27 13:42:13"
      ["attivo"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

I need to modify the img value by putting the head (http://www.example.com/folder/) of url in before it and then rewrite back the value to the object before sending it to the json encode.

I tried the following but maybe I'm having the wrong approach to the problem.

```
foreach ($rows as $k => $value) {
    if($k == 'img'){
        echo $rows['img'] = "http://example.com/folder/".$value->img;
    }
}
```

can you give me a direction please?

Comment: What is the value of `$directory`? Did you notice you're trying to change `$rows` in each iteration instead of `$value`? And there is a `each` helper which I think will help you in this case https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-each

Comment: why you downvoted my question? Please give a reason...

Comment: @Nima yes, I'm trying to rewrite `$rows['img']` as I wrote in the question

Comment: `$rows` is a collection of objects which every one of them has an `img` property, not the `$rows` itself. Also iterating over all object properties (which I think you intended to do, but your code actually does not that) to find the `img` key, and then do something with it is strange and makes your question unclear, because you can simply use `['img']` or `->img` to access that key/property. Please give an example of current output and desired output of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I had to use `map` as:

```
$rows->map(function ($value) {
   $value->img = 'http://example.com/img/'. $value->img;
});
```